# Facebook fan page interaction

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I've seen a lot of questions on here asking how to publish **to** a Facebook fan page, but not how to publish **from** a Facebook fan page to an external site.

I'm admin of a fan page and would like to make updates for my audience from Facebook. These updates I'd like to appear on my website as well. Does anybody know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pull feed messages in json format like so:

http://graph.facebook.com/17227611925/feed

Substitute 17227611925 with the id of your page.

You'd have to find/write a bit of code to do this.  Do you already have some sort of server-side programming environment set up?

Comment: Oh, perfect! Simple and exactly what I needed. Yeah, I can take care of the backend programming.